# Are these isomorphic $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{9}^{*}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is  $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{9}^{*}$

both have orders 6

both have elements with orders 1,2,3,6 (1 element of order 1, 2 elements of order 3, 1 element of order 2 and 2 elements of order 6)

Both are cyclic thus Abelian

Can I assume then that they are isomorphic? Or a specific isomorphism must be constructed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the two groups are isomorphic. And you are *almost* there in proving this.

Note that $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_3 = \mathbb Z_6$, since $\gcd(2, 3) = 1$.

And since the order of $\mathbb Z^*_9 = 6$ and is cyclic, we know that $\mathbb Z^*_9 \cong \mathbb Z_6$.

There is no need to construct an explicit isomorphism here, though you need to (implicitly or explicitly) invoke the following standard fact about finite cyclic groups:

> Every finite cyclic group of order $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_n$, the group of integers under addition, modulo $n$.

Comment: thank you for reminding me this useful theorem, I forgot about it:)

Comment: You're welcome, Heidi! ;-)

Comment: +1 @amWhy  Im  not  getting How order of $\mathbb Z^*_9 = 6?$  I think order of  $\mathbb Z^*_9$ is $9-1=8$

Answer (score 3):

You've already got 99% of what you need to make an isomorphism anyhow, so you should :)

You noted that they both have elements of order $6$, so that they are both cyclic groups of order 6. Just send one generator to a generator of the other one and convince yourself it's an isomorphism.